# Maven : Using class from imported jar

Tags: java, maven

I'm quite new in Maven.
I'm trying to do following:
Suppose we have to projects A and B. Project B needs to use some classfrom_A from jar imported from A
Here are definitions :
POM.xml of project A :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>A_Group</groupId>
  <artifactId>A_Artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>A_Project</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
</project>
```

Here is POM.xml of project B (depends on A ) :

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>B_Group</groupId>
    <artifactId>B_Artifact</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>B_Project</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>A_Group</groupId>
            <artifactId>A_Artifact</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Here is code snippet from project B:

```java
import packageFromA.*;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    classFromA ca = new ClassFromA; //from packageFromA 
    ca.someFunction();            
    }
}
```

I run mvn install for A , then for B with no errors 
But when trying to run code above from IntelliJ Idea, got error : 
Error:(3, 18) java: package  packageFromA does not exist

As I understand from maven docs : "compile dependencies are available in all classpaths, and they are packaged". But it seems that imported class still was not resolved . What was missing in the definitions ? Thanks in advance

UPDATE: When running from IntelliJ the issue was resolved after re-import. But when I run from command line
`java projectB`
Do I need explicitly set classpath of imported jars? If yes do I need point to i's location im local maven repository (.m2/repository) ? Thanks

Comment: The `pom.xml`s seem to be good, this is more likely an IDE issue. Have you checked the generated `jar`s?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Generated jar for project A contains classFromA.class file. Should mvn install of A update classpath ?

Comment: But does project B contains the project A `jar` file? If it does, then this is an IDE issue.

Comment: No, jar of B does not contain jar from A. So as I understand it is importing issue, is it correct ? which settings should be checked here ? More infor - both project are installed on same local repository .Thanks

Comment: Use `mvn package` after `install`.

Comment: Tried for both projects - the issue was not resolved

Comment: Then, I am out of ideas (pun intended :) ), as I am not familiar with IDEA.

Comment: search maven projects in intellij and refresh your project.

Comment: Do i need to modify manually classpath ?

Comment: Yes you have to manually provide complete path of jar in the classpath.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. So if jar imported , I should provide it's path in .m2/repository - it's location after import - is it correct ?

Answer (score 3):

In your POM for project B you can add a configuration for the maven-jar-plugin to generate a MANIFEST file which contains the classpath:

```
<project>
  ...
  <build>
    <plugins>
      ...
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      ...
    </plugins>
  </build> 

</project>
```

This will set up the classpath attribute in your MANIFEST file, which expects all dependend jar libraries in a sub directory `lib/` of your main jar. You need to copy these libraries manually in the `lib` directory.

To distribute your application with all dependend libraries using maven, you can use the [maven assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/).

Hope it helps!